# Moving a div by it's id on button click of the appropriate desired direction by 'x'px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move a div with id="obj" by 15px towards the desired directions by clicking on the appropraite buttons (i.e Up,Down,Right,Left and Random). I used setinterval but it moves the object from one end to the opposite end, i searched for similar questions but their solutions didn't fir my case.

**Here is the Html:**

```
<div id="box">
   <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
      <tr valign="top">
         <td width="20%">
             <input type="button" class="b" value="Gauche" onclick="Gauche()"/>
             <input type="button" class="b" value="Droite" onclick="Droite()"/>
             <input type="button" class="b" value="Haut" onclick="Haut()"/>
             <input type="button" class="b" value="Bas" onclick="Bas()"/>
             <input type="button" class="b" value="Aléatoire" onclick="Aléatoire()"/>
        </td>
        <td height="100%" width="100%">
            <div id="obj"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
/*styling our div containing the table*/
        #box{
            position: absolute;
            height:820px;
            width:1000px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
        /*styling the table*/
        table{
            position: relative;
        }
        /*styling the buttons*/
        .b{
            padding:5px;
            size: 40px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 500;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        /*styling the object*/
       #obj{
            border: 1px black;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 75px;
            width: 75px;
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            left:1px;
       }
```

**Here is the javascript :**

```
//The Right() button function:
function Droite(){
    var posx = 0;
    var box = document.getElementById("obj");
    var t = setInterval(moveRight);

    function moveRight(){
        if(posx >= 715){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else{
            posx += 15;
            document.getElementById("obj").style.left = posx +'px';
            this.posx = posx;
        }
    } 
}

//The Left() button function:
function Gauche(){
    var posx = 720;
    var box = document.getElementById("obj");
    var t = setInterval(moveLeft);

    function moveLeft(){
        if(posx <= 1){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else{
            posx -= 15;
            document.getElementById("obj").style.left = posx +'px'; 
        }
    }
}

//The Down() button function:
function Bas(){
    var posy = 0;
    var box = document.getElementById("obj");
    var t = setInterval(moveDown);

    function moveDown(){
        if(posy >= 735){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else{
            posy += 15;
            document.getElementById("obj").style.top = posy +'px';
        }
    }
}

//The Up() button function:
function haut(){
    var posy = 720;
    var box = document.getElementById("obj");
    var t = setInterval(moveUp);

    function moveUp(){
        if(posy <= 1){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else{
            posy -= 15;
            document.getElementById("obj").style.top = posy +'px';
        }
    }
}

/*The Random() button function*/
function Aléatoire(){

    //Some code to move the div elt at a random position
}
```

The buttons' values are written in French(i'm bilingual), so here are their translations: Gauche = 'Left', Droite ='Right',Haut='Up', Bas='Down' and Aléatoire='Random'.

Comment: `function haut()` should be `function Haut()`

Comment: Yeah, its an error from when i was editing my question

Comment: And no,  I didn't get it there and btw i search there and couldn't get a useful thing since w3schools mainly work with html canvas.

Comment: Would you mind helping me? Please

Comment: Ok is the problem that when for example click Droite goes to the right side and then click the same button once again takes it back to left and then moves it back to right?

Comment: Yeah exactly, same for all the rest.

Comment: Ok give me five minutes

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval` here? This will repeat the function. This is why the box is moving more than 15px with each click.

Comment: @JonP i know that the issue is setInterval but i don't know what to use instead. And i tried using parseInt (with the the object's id and string position as arguments) ... but it didn't work. So either i didn't write the code correct, either none of parseInt/ setInterval are the methods to be used here.

Comment: do you want the box to slide 15px, in say 1px increments instead of jumping 15px on each button click?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I made for you

```js
var pos = [0, 0], box = document.querySelector("#box");
document.querySelector("#controls").onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    switch(e.target.textContent) {
      case "Right": {
        box.style.left = `${pos[0] + 15 > 300 ? 300 : pos[0] += 15}px`;
        break;
      }
      case "Left": {
        box.style.left = `${pos[0] - 15 < 0 ? 0 : pos[0] -= 15}px`;
        break;
      }
      case "Down": {
        box.style.top = `${pos[1] + 15 > 300 ? 300 : pos[1] += 15}px`;
        break;
      }
      case "Up": {
        box.style.top = `${pos[1] - 15 < 0 ? 0 : pos[1] -= 15}px`;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#controls {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
}
#controls button {
  width: 25%;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <button>Left</button>
  <button>Right</button>
  <button>Down</button>
  <button>Up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution: the Gauche &amp; Droite buttons work but still not in steps of 15px and only for the first clicks. The Haut &amp; Bas buttons are no more working and the Random seems to use only the Gauche/ Droite functions, not in steps of 15px still.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to be moving 15px by 15px and takes some time between the moves?

Comment: Yes it should move 15px by 15px but without time delay, ie for example it should move 15px to the left every time i click on the 'Gauche' button.

Comment: Ah ok I get it now, and do you want it to still animate or just moves at once

Comment: @user12867860 take a look on my post, I have just edited it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pos = {x: 0, y: 0};
var box = document.querySelector("#obj");
var container = document.querySelector("#container");

var moveTimeOut;

//The Right() button function:
function Droite() {
    clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
    moveTimeOut = setInterval(() => {
        if ((pos.x + 15) <= (container.offsetWidth - box.offsetWidth)) {
            pos.x = pos.x + 15;
        } else {
            pos.x = (container.offsetWidth - box.offsetWidth);
            clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
        }
        box.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
    }, 300);
}

//The Left() button function:
function Gauche() {
    clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
    moveTimeOut = setInterval(() => {
        if ((pos.x + 15) >= box.offsetWidth) {
            pos.x = pos.x - 15;
        } else {
            pos.x = 0;
            clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
        }
        box.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
    }, 300);
}

//The Down() button function:
function Bas() {
    clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
    moveTimeOut = setInterval(() => {
        if ((pos.y + 15) <= (container.offsetHeight - box.offsetHeight)) {
            pos.y = pos.y + 15;
        } else {
            pos.y = (container.offsetHeight - box.offsetHeight);
            clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
        }
        box.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
    }, 300);
}

//The Up() button function:
function haut() {
    clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
    moveTimeOut = setInterval(() => {
        if ((pos.y + 15) >= box.offsetHeight) {
            pos.y = pos.y - 15;
        } else {
            pos.y = 0;
            clearInterval(moveTimeOut);
        }
        box.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
    }, 300);
}

/*The Random() button function*/
function Aléatoire() {

    //Some code to move the div elt at a random position
}
```

```css
/*styling our div containing the table*/
#box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 820px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

/*styling the table*/
table {
    position: relative;
}

/*styling the buttons*/
.b {
    padding: 5px;
    size: 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/*styling the object*/
#obj {
    border: 1px black;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="button" class="b" value="Gauche" onclick="Gauche()"/>
                <input type="button" class="b" value="Droite" onclick="Droite()"/>
                <input type="button" class="b" value="Haut" onclick="haut()"/>
                <input type="button" class="b" value="Bas" onclick="Bas()"/>
                <input type="button" class="b" value="Aléatoire" onclick="Aléatoire()"/>
            </td>
            <td id="container" height="100%" width="100%">
                <div id="obj"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it works only for the first click.